# How to change the colour of hamburger menu when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the colour of the hamburger menu when it's clicked.

The colour of the hamburger menu is the same colour as the background of the menu when opened.

I want to change the colour of the hamburger menu to white when the menu appears. And return to blue when it's clicked and the menu disappears.

HTML

```
<nav class="nav" id="home">

        <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>

        <div class="navbar-links">

          <ul class="nav-list">

            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#home" class="nav-link">home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about-me" class="nav-link">about me</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#services" class="nav-link">services</a></li>
            <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a href="#portfolio" class="nav-link">portfolio</a></li> -->
            <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a href="#blog" class="nav-link">blog</a></li> -->
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">contact</a></li>
            <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a href="#work" class="nav__link">Work</a></li> -->

          </ul>

        </div>

      </nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--clr-main);
}

.nav-item {
  margin-right: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-link{
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--clr-secondary);
  font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
  display: block;
}

.nav-list{
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item:hover{
  background-color: #00a6ff;
}

.toggle-button{
  position: absolute;
  top: 18px;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 31px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar{
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  /* background-color: var(--clr-secondary); */
  background-color: var(--clr-main);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The hamburger menu only shows when the page is 600px or less in width.

var(--clr-primary) is blue.

var(--clr-secondary) is white.

```
@media (max-width: 600px){

  .toggle-button{
    display: flex;
  }

  .nav{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .navbar-links{
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }

  .navbar-links.active{
    display: flex;
  }

  .nav-list{
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .nav-item{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 0;
  }

}
```

JS

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-button")[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar-links")[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle("active")
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try toggling a class on the toggle button with js, and adding some css to change color:

```js
toggleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle("active");
  toggleButton.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.toggle-button {
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

.toggle-button.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```